# Beautiful Soup - extracting after the div

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup,Tag
import requests

url=r"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_tourist_attractions"

r = requests.get(url)
soup = Soup(r.content,"html.parser" )

for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print (link['href'])

for ul in soup.findAll('div'):
    print(ul.text)
    for li in ul.findAll('li'):
        print(li.text)
```

The above one is a working code. This can e used any Wikipedia pages.
Issue is :
I am trying to get 
href and title next to each other . I am not able to get this.

in the 2nd for loop its taking all the contents as div and prints in one line.

how can I print title and href adjutant to each other (li contents)

Comment: can you be more specific with what you want?  `how can I print title and href adjutant to each other (li contents)` i dont understand this sentence

Comment: do you just want to have the list of temples printed out with their urls next to them?

Comment: In the wiki there are many contents in <li>. which has title and a href. I am looking at printing them.

Comment: right now with my program I can print all hrefs, all title but not both adjustant

Comment: yeah because you have them in separate loops. The logic you use is too simple. I would at least make use of arrays if i was you, and print the array when the scraping  has finished. Or create a txt file or something and keep it nice and clean there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print (link.get('href') +'->' + link.get('title'))
```

Btw, I would  suggest to use `wikipedia API` or `special:export` feature to access the data.

> https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page 
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Export

Comment: Thankq pankay it works but why is the url not complete. its missing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's not what you are looking for, but you can try this one. I made a small modification on your both `for` loop:

```
for lnk in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
    title = (lnk.text)
    link = (lnk['href'])
    if title != '':
        print ("Title: {}, Link: https://en.wikipedia.org{}".format(title, link))
```

Comment: This is not working ...its only giving hrefs and tite

Comment: If not href and title that you want to extract, so what do you mean with your statement "I am trying to get href and title next to each other. I am not able to get this."

Comment: I mean its not printing the title but just the word title and href

Comment: Ok, I made a further modification